# Add class when div tag is getting overflowed

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css

I have a `div` with fixed height and width, I'm adding some content in it using `ng-repeat`, I want to add a class on this div when this is getting overflowed. I tried to add class with `length` but didn't work.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('personCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.placeholder = ['Koenigsegg CCXR Trevita',
    'Lamborghini Veneno',
    'W Motors Lykan Hypersport',
    'Bugatti Veyron',
    'Ferrari Pininfarina Sergio',
    'Pagani Huayra BC',
    'Ferrari F60 America',
    'Bugatti Chiron',
    'Koenigsegg One',
    'Koenigsegg Regera'
  ];
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 40px;
  width: 400px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 5px;
}
span {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="personCtrl">
  <span ng-repeat="j in placeholder;">
    {{j}} &times;
  </span>

</div>
```

**Note:** I can only use `javascript` or `angularjs`

Comment: Why do you need that class, what is the goal?

Comment: I want to show `filtered queries` but when div is full with `filtered queries` I want to add `view more` in that div @skobaljic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need only to add some class when there is too much items in array, you can use ng-class attribute.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('personCtrl', function($scope) {

});
```

```css
div{height:100px;width:100px;background:#f2f2f2;border:1px solid #000}
div.too-long {background-color: #FF6666}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="personCtrl" ng-class="{'too-long': placeholder.length > 6}" ng-init="placeholder=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]">
  <span ng-repeat="j in placeholder;">
    {{j}} Content
  </span>

</div>
```

But if you need to compare content size and div size, you can use offsetHeight and scrollHeight properties of your div

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('personCtrl', function($scope, $element) {
    $scope.placeholder = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]
    $scope.overflow = function() {
        return $element[0].scrollHeight > $element[0].offsetHeight;
    }
});
```

```css
div{height:100px;width:100px;background:#f2f2f2;border:1px solid #000}
div.too-long {background-color: #FF6666}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="personCtrl" ng-class="{'too-long': overflow()}">
  <span ng-repeat="j in placeholder;">
    {{j}} Content
  </span>

</div>
```